# How to create a shortcut menu in ms access?

Tags: ms-access

How to create a shortcut menu in ms access? By shortcut menu I mean when user right click and a menu shows up.

Below is the code I wrote to create this shortcut menu but getting an error.

**Compile error**: User-defined type not defined

**On Line**: Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReportShortcutMenu()
    Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
    Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

   ' Create the shortcut menu.
    Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("cmdReportRightClick", msoBarPopup, False, True)

    With cmbRightClick

        ' Add the Print command.
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 2521, , , True)
        ' Change the caption displayed for the control.
        cmbControl.Caption = "Quick Print"

        ' Add the Print command.
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 15948, , , True)
        ' Change the caption displayed for the control.
        cmbControl.Caption = "Select Pages"

        ' Add the Page Setup... command.
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 247, , , True)
        ' Change the caption displayed for the control.
        cmbControl.Caption = "Page Setup"

        ' Add the Mail Recipient (as Attachment)... command.
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 2188, , , True)
        ' Start a new group.
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        ' Change the caption displayed for the control.
        cmbControl.Caption = "Email Report as an Attachment"

        ' Add the PDF or XPS command.
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12499, , , True)
        ' Change the caption displayed for the control.
        cmbControl.Caption = "Save as PDF/XPS"

        ' Add the Close command.
        Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 923, , , True)
        ' Start a new group.
        cmbControl.BeginGroup = True
        ' Change the caption displayed for the control.
        cmbControl.Caption = "Close Report"
    End With

    Set cmbControl = Nothing
    Set cmbRightClick = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()
    CreateReportShortcutMenu
End Sub
```

Comment: This is way over my head, but some research seems to indicate that you need to declare `.CommandBar` at the class level. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scff9c7c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: No, they are fine as local variables.

Answer (score 4):

In the VBA Editor, open Tools -> References, and check the reference **Microsoft Office xx.0 Object Library** (with xx being your Office version, e.g. 14 for Office 2010).

With this reference, Access will recognize `Office.CommandBar` and the compile error will be gone.

**But**: you will need to add some things to make this work.

The commandbar `"cmdReportRightClick"` you are creating is permanently stored in the database. You will need to delete it on closing of the report:

```
CommandBars("cmdReportRightClick").Delete
```

or check for its existence before creating it.

And you need to assign it to the report:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    CreateReportShortcutMenu
    Me.ShortcutMenuBar = "cmdReportRightClick"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

For those Office 365 Desktop users, note that the name of the reference may be `Office` instead of `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library`. Access won't recognize  `Office.CommandBar`  without this reference.

This is a different reference from `Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine object`.
This took me a while to figure out.

[image]

Comment: That reference looks weird... especially the generic name. Can you check which exact file (e.g. DLL) it refers to? For Office 365 (Version 16), it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL`.

Comment: as expected I was able to use the command bar with the microsoft office 16 object library